# Subscript out of range within Do-Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following partial code and my for loop breaks ONLY on the 35th tab when I try to activate. The code runs correctly for sheets 6-33. I deleted sheet 34 so I'm thinking it might be because it "jumps" to sheet 35. However, when I debug and place the cursor over endTab I see it contains the value 35. The activate for some reason doesn't work only on this sheet and breaks. Any thoughts?

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim startRow As Long
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim endTab As Integer

Sheets(4).activate

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
startRow = 2

Range("A2:AB" & lastRow).Sort key1:=Range("AB2:AB" & lastRow), _
    order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

For i = startRow To lastRow
    Sheets(4).activate
    endTab = Range("AB" & startRow + i - 2)

    Range("A" & startRow + i - 2 & ":" & "AB" & startRow + i - 2).Copy
    Worksheets(endTab).activate
    Columns("A").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "A")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next
```

Comment: Any hidden/veryhidden sheets?

Comment: No, I can see the sheet list on the VBAProject window and can see Sheet35(Not Classified) and my endTab value reads 35.

Comment: if `Worksheets(endTab).activate` errors and endTab=35 that indicates you don't have 35 sheets.  Not sure why else you'd see that.  Is that code copied directly from your workbook?  `activate` should be capitalized, so did you edit after copying?

Comment: It is copied directly, which is confusing as to why it didn't capitalize. It's actually still not capitalizing, but the code is running. I definitely have a sheet35 because I can see it listed to the left of my code... Thanks already for the help!

Comment: Sheet code names are created when the sheet is first created - they do not adjust to match the order of the sheets in the workbook.  Your code is addressing "the 35th sheet" (couting your sheet tabs from left to right) which is not the necessarily the sheet with the codename of "Sheet35"

Comment: That explains my issue. I'll need to find a work around. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

From comments:

Sheet code names are created when the sheet is first created - they do not adjust to match the order of the sheets in the workbook. Your code is addressing "the 35th sheet" (counting your sheet tabs from left to right) which is not the necessarily the sheet with the codename of "Sheet35"